# jQuery multiple input changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, slider

I am trying to use jQuery to change some HTML text by changing a slider, I figured out how to do that, but I also need to do it only if a checkbox is on, how do I put both in, and then how do I make it only do it when the checkbox is clicked, I am doing this with arrays, because I'm trying to do it in time, not decimals. Here is the link to my current code: https://codepen.io/2cheeky4you/pen/QqGKpy

```
$(document).on('input change', '#range-slider', '#voiceover', function() { 
  //Listen to slider changes (input changes)
  var v=$(this).val(); //Create a Variable (v), and store the value of the input change (Ex. Image 2 [imageURL])
  var q = document.querySelector('input[id="voiceover"]');
  var voiceovermain = ["<span>$0.00</span>",voiceoverslider[0]];
  $('#sliderStatus').html(imageUrl[v]);
  $('#sliderPrice').html( sizeRange[v] );
  $('#voiceoverslider').html( sizeRange[v] );
  $('#voiceoverspan').html( voiceover[q] );  
  $("#img").prop("src", imageUrl[v]); // Modify the Images attribute src based on the sliders value, and input the value inside the imageURL[v] to display image
});
```

This is one of my first times using the code thing on this website, so pardon my messed up whitespaces.

I English very well :) so I'm sorry if something doesn't make sense. Just tell me in the comments if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wish to show two prices based on the slider position, one being optionnal depending on the checkbox.

You array idea is not the best way to do it. I think you should use the slider value as an integer and calculate your prices with it.

So the first thing is to define your two prices. Then simply do some maths.
I defined your second price as $5 per slider knotch (which is 5 seconds of video duration), for this example.

Feel free to ask questions about the code if there is anything unclear.

```js
var sliderUnit = 5; // 5 seconds of video duration per slider notch

var basePrice = 100;
var price = 10;
var subPrice = 5; 

$(document).on('input change', '#range-slider, #voiceover', function() { //Listen to slider changes (input changes)
  
  var slider=parseInt($('#range-slider').val());
  var voiceOption = $('#voiceover');
  
  console.log(slider); // returns an integer from 0 to 34

  // Time
  var seconds = (slider*5)%60;
  var minutes = Math.floor(slider*5/60);
  if(seconds<10){seconds= "0"+seconds}  // Leading zero
  $('#sliderStatus').html('<span>'+minutes+":"+seconds+'</span>');
  
  // Price for video duration
  var price1 = (slider*price) +basePrice;
  $('#sliderPrice').html('<span>$'+price1+'.00</span>');

  // Price for voiceover
  var price2 = slider*subPrice;
  if( voiceOption.is(":checked") ){
    $('#voiceoverspan').html('<span>$'+price2+'.00</span>');
  }else{
    $('#voiceoverspan').html('<span>$0.00</span>');
  }

});


// ::::: Range Slider Thumb ::::: //
$("#range-slider").on("mousedown mouseup", function() { //1. When user clicks their mouse down on the Range-Slider
  $(this).toggleClass("thumb-down hover-ring thumb-up hover-ring-out");
});
```

```css
#slider_count {
  margin:0px auto;
  width:200px;
  padding:20px 20px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:yellow;
}

/* ::::::::::::::::::::Range Slider Styles::::::::::::::::::::::::: */
.range-slider-block {
  margin:0px auto;
  width:90%;
}
#range-slider {
  padding:40px 0px;
  width:100%;
  /*outline: 1px solid green;*/
}
/* Remove Range Sliders Default Styles*/
input[type=range]{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
/* Track */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 10px;
  background: #d7d7d7;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
/* Thumb */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #46947F;
  margin-top: -9px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}
input[type=range]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10pt rgba(190,190,190,0.4);
  cursor:pointer;
}

/* JS Stykes */
/* Changes Thumb color to darker green when mousedownn */
input[type=range].thumb-down::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background:#316557;
}
/* Changes Thumb color back to light green when mouseup */
input[type=range].thumb-up::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background:#46947F;  
}
/* Changes Ring color Green */
input[type=range].hover-ring::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6pt rgba(70,148,127,0.46);
  cursor:pointer;
}
input[type=range].hover-ring-out::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0pt rgba(0,0,0,0);
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="range-slider-block">
    <input type="range" id="range-slider" class="thumb-up hover-ring-out" value="0.0" min="0" max="34" step="1" />
  </div>

  <div id="slider_count">Time = <span id="sliderStatus">0:00</span></div>
  <br/>
  <div id="slider_count">Subprice (Video Duration) = <span id="sliderPrice">$0.00</span></div>
  <br/>
  <label for="voiceover">Would you like a voiceover?</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="voiceover" name="voiceover" checked>
  <div id="slider_count">Subprice (for voiceover): = <span id="voiceoverspan">$0.00</span></div>
</form>
```

Notice that I also improved the handler to add/remove classes on the slider...

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/GMNBQx?editors=1011)

Comment: Yep, I noticed that you improved the handler, thank you, that will make the whole project a whole lot easier. I am trying to make some point of constructive criticism in every comment I write so here I go, what if someone were to want other numbers, or a non-linear equation (I am not saying I need it, I'm just being a Devil's Advocate and I'm very sorry)?

Comment: ;) Great to read that. About you're devil advocate question, I just would angel answer that the only thing you actually know from the page user is that slider position.
Do the devil's math you want with it. A non-linear equation can be handled by this script... But it may need some other inputs to make it "math" (no devil/angel). And that is up to you to desing. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I found the issue with your code and put a new codepen up: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzbBOx?editors=1111

Imediately after

```
function() {
```

you should put:

```
var check = $('#voiceover')[0];
if (check.checked) {

    // your entire function's code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a section to your code and modified it a little. Basically I added an if statement that checked if the check was on or not and then copied the value of the slider price into it. Of course you can do anything you want with the value but I was not sure exactly what value you wanted for the subprice. Good luck.

```js
var sizeRange = [" <span>$100.00</span>",
  " <span>$110.00</span>",
  "<span>$120.00</span>",
  "<span>$130.00</span>",
  "<span>$140.00</span>",
  "<span>$150.00</span>",
  " <span>$160.00</span>",
  " <span>$170.00</span>",
  " <span>$180.00</span>",
  " <span>$190.00</span>",
  " <span>$200.00</span>",
  " <span>$210.00</span>",
  " <span>$220.00</span>",
  " <span>$230.00</span>",
  " <span>$240.00</span>",
  " <span>$250.00</span>",
  " <span>$260.00</span>",
  " <span>$270.00</span>",
  " <span>$280.00</span>",
  " <span>$290.00</span>",
  " <span>$300.00</span>",
  " <span>$310.00</span>",
  " <span>$320.00</span>",
  " <span>$350.00</span>",
  " <span>$380.00</span>",
  " <span>$410.00</span>",
  " <span>$440.00</span>",
  " <span>$470.00</span>",
  " <span>$500.00</span>",
  " <span>$530.00</span>",
  " <span>$560.00</span>",
  " <span>$590.00</span>",
  " <span>$620.00</span>",
  " <span>$650.00</span>",
  " <span>$680.00</span>"
];


var imageUrl = [" <span>:10</span>",
  " <span>:15</span>",
  "<span>:20</span>",
  "<span>:25</span>",
  "<span>:30</span>",
  "<span>:35</span>",
  " <span>:40</span>",
  " <span>:45</span>",
  " <span>:50</span>",
  " <span>:55</span>",
  " <span>1:00</span>",
  " <span>1:05</span>",
  " <span>1:10</span>",
  " <span>1:15</span>",
  " <span>1:20</span>",
  " <span>1:25</span>",
  " <span>1:30</span>",
  " <span>1:35</span>",
  " <span>1:40</span>",
  " <span>1:45</span>",
  " <span>1:50</span>",
  " <span>1:55</span>",
  " <span>2:00</span>",
  " <span>2:15</span>",
  " <span>2:30</span>",
  " <span>2:45</span>",
  " <span>3:00</span>",
  " <span>3:15</span>",
  " <span>3:30</span>",
  " <span>3:45</span>",
  " <span>4:00</span>",
  " <span>4:15</span>",
  " <span>4:30</span>",
  " <span>4:45</span>",
  " <span>5:00</span>",
]; //adds the times instead of regular numbers.
var voiceoverslider = [" <span>$100.00</span>",
  " <span>$110.00</span>",
  "<span>$120.00</span>",
  "<span>$130.00</span>",
  "<span>$140.00</span>",
  "<span>$150.00</span>",
  " <span>$160.00</span>",
  " <span>$170.00</span>",
  " <span>$180.00</span>",
  " <span>$190.00</span>",
  " <span>$200.00</span>",
  " <span>$210.00</span>",
  " <span>$220.00</span>",
  " <span>$230.00</span>",
  " <span>$240.00</span>",
  " <span>$250.00</span>",
  " <span>$260.00</span>",
  " <span>$270.00</span>",
  " <span>$280.00</span>",
  " <span>$290.00</span>",
  " <span>$300.00</span>",
  " <span>$310.00</span>",
  " <span>$320.00</span>",
  " <span>$350.00</span>",
  " <span>$380.00</span>",
  " <span>$410.00</span>",
  " <span>$440.00</span>",
  " <span>$470.00</span>",
  " <span>$500.00</span>",
  " <span>$530.00</span>",
  " <span>$560.00</span>",
  " <span>$590.00</span>",
  " <span>$620.00</span>",
  " <span>$650.00</span>",
  " <span>$680.00</span>"
];

$('#sliderPrice').html(sizeRange[0]);
 
$("#voiceover").on("change",function(){
 
});



$(document).on("change", '#range-slider', function() { //Listen to slider changes (input changes)
  var v = $(this).val(); //Create a Variable (v), and store the value of the input change (Ex. Image 2 [imageURL])
  var q = $("#slider_count").val();
  var voiceovermain = ["<span>$0.00</span>",
    voiceoverslider[0]
  ];
  $('#sliderStatus').html(imageUrl[v]);
  $('#sliderPrice').html(sizeRange[v]);
  $('#voiceoverslider').html(sizeRange[v]);
  
   //---------------------------------------------------------
  if($("#voiceover").is(":checked")){    
    $("#voiceoverspan").html("");
    $('#sliderPrice').clone().appendTo("#voiceoverspan");
  } else {
    $('#voiceoverspan').html("$0.00");
  }
 //-----------------------------------------------------------


  $("#img").prop("src", imageUrl[v]); // Modify the Images attribute src based on the sliders value, and input the value inside the imageURL[v] to display image
});

// ::::: Range Slider Thumb ::::: //

$("#range-slider").on("mousedown", function() { //1. When user clicks their mouse down on the Range-Slider
  $(this).removeClass().addClass("thumb-down"); //1.1 Remove default class from CSS, and add the class .thumb-down (changes background color)
  $(this).addClass("hover-ring"); //1.2 Remove default class from CSS, and add the class .hover-ring (changes box-shadow to a green color)
});

$("#range-slider").on("mouseup", function() { //2. When user mouse-up on Range-Slider

  $(this).addClass("thumb-up"); //2.1 Changes thumb color back to light green

  $(this).addClass("hover-ring-out"); //2.2 Remove Box-Shadow
});
```

```css
#slider_count {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}


/* ::::::::::::::::::::Range Slider Styles::::::::::::::::::::::::: */

.range-slider-block {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 90%;
}

#range-slider {
  padding: 40px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  /*outline: 1px solid green;*/
}


/* Remove Range Sliders Default Styles*/

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


/* Track */

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 10px;
  background: #d7d7d7;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* Thumb */

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #46947F;
  margin-top: -9px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}

input[type=range]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10pt rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* JS Stykes */


/* Changes Thumb color to darker green when mousedownn */

input[type=range].thumb-down::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #316557;
}


/* Changes Thumb color back to light green when mouseup */

input[type=range].thumb-up::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #46947F;
}


/* Changes Ring color Green */

input[type=range].hover-ring::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6pt rgba(70, 148, 127, 0.46);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range].hover-ring-out::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0pt rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="range-slider-block">
    <input type="range" id="range-slider" value="0.0" min="0" max="34" step="1" />
  </div>

  <div id="slider_count">Time = <span id="sliderStatus">:10</span></div>
  <br/>
  <div id="slider_count">Subprice (Video Duration) = <span id="sliderPrice">$0.00</span></div>
  <br/>
  <label for="voiceover">Would you like a voiceover?</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="voiceover" name="voiceover" checked>
  <div id="slider_count">Subprice (for voiceover): = <span id="voiceoverspan">$0.00</span></div>
</form>
```